# Is there a resource which lists Ubuntu Security Notices?

Tags: updates, security, patch, vulnerability

Every week, I check the [Ubuntu Security Notices page](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn), to see what's going on in the world of vulnerabilities.

**Is there anywhere the information from these posts is kept in a more reviewable format?**

It takes quite a while opening each page and gleaning the pertinent information. It'd be great to be able to see which releases are affected by each security notice, and which package upgrades are necessary to fix these, especially in a table like format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a one-to-one correspondence, but you can use [the Ubuntu CVE trackers](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/), maintained by the Ubuntu Security team. For example, the tracker for software in `main` is http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/main.html:

[image]

Comment: I should have known it was you even before upvoting!  ;-)